# Fazer div desaparecer

Tags: html, div

Tenho um código que ele só funciona se manter uma `<div id="panel">`, mas não gostaria que ela aparecesse na tela. Tem como manter essa div, mas deixar ele invisível?

Comment: Quando dizes _"código que ele só funciona se manter uma `<div id="panel">`"_ fico curioso que código é esse? Acho que seria interessante resolver isso na fonte do que estar a esconder.

Answer (score 2):

Ou no próprio **CSS**:

```
<div id="panel" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
```

ou

```
#panel { visibility:hidden; }
```

Só não faz muito sentido, ou não entendi bem.

Answer (score 2):

Para deixa invisivel/esconder a `div` você pode fazer assim:

```
$("#panel").hide() ou $("#panel").css("display", "none")
```

O problema é se você estiver fazendo alguma validação pra verificar se a `div` está visível:

```
$("#panel").is(":visible")
```

Então você terá que alterar a validação para verificar se a `div` existe:

```
if($("#panel").length > 0)
   //div existe
```

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver usando **jQuery**.

`$('#sua-div').css('visibility', 'hidden');`

Se estiver usando **JavaScript**.

`document.getElementById('sua-div').style.visibility = 'hidden';`

Answer (score 1):

Se você usar `style="display:none;"` a sua div estará lá, mas não será visível. Veja abaixo um exemplo.

```js
function mostraDiv(id,div2)
{
var divstyle = new String();        
divstyle = document.getElementById(id).style.display;

var divAux = new String();        
divAux = document.getElementById(div2).style.display;
      
      if (divAux=="block" || divAux == ""){
    document.getElementById(div2).style.display = "none";
 }   
 
 document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block"; 
 return false;  
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="displayDiv('teste','teste2')"> </a> 
<a href="#" onclick="displayDiv('teste2','teste')"> </a> 

<div id="teste">
  teste
</div>

<div id="teste2" style="display:none;">
  teste2
</div>
```

Fonte: [Esse post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/Hh475808.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

complementado acima, se estiver usando angularJS.

`<div id="panel" ng-show="false">`